# How can I find IP/web console for a wireless AP

Tags: networking, switch, wifi, access-point, wlan

I have a Dlink DWL-2600AP, it is working but I'd like to do some troubleshooting on it (it's acting as if client isolation has magically turned on after 2 years, which is a problem for our wireless printers).

It's connected to a port on our 2960x #2 switch, that port is on a VLAN for our WLAN, and the 2960x #1 Switch does DHCP for that WLAN/VLAN (trunk between Switch #1 and #2). I did a `sh mac-address-table` on the interface the WAP is plugged into and found a MAC address that appears to be a DLINK device from a lookup.

However I tried `sh ip arp | inc <that mac>` on router but nothing came up. Tried `sh ip arp vlan #` on the #1 switch that does DHCP but that mac address did not appear. Is it possible the web console is disabled for the AP? Is there anything else can I try to track it down?

Manually connecting to the console port of the AP is going to be difficult and is a last resort if I can't find another way in.

Answer (score 1):

The ARP table would only be populated if the router or the switch themselves needed to communicate with the AP, which they would almost never need to do. Run a subnet ip address scan and look for the IP address associated with the MAC address of the AP.

Comment: So if the clients are connecting to the AP in the same VLAN and getting DHCP from the switch, the AP is not actually communicating with the switch? I have tried Angry IP scanner to the block of IPs allotted to the WLAN's VLAN but did not see the Mac address anywhere. It's also possible that the AP is in a completely different network like 10.0... or 172.16...

Comment: The AP operates at Layer 2, just like a traditional Layer 2 switch does. There would be almost no reason for the switch, router, or any other device to communicate with the AP at Layer 3.

Comment: I confirmed it is the correct Mac Address of the wireless AP with 'wifi analyzer' on my Android smartphone. Since it's not showing up in an IP scan of that subnet is there anything else I can try?

Comment: It's entirely possible that the AP doesn't have an ip address. It's not a requirement that it has one... although that would make it difficult to configure and manage it if it didn't have one. Might it be the case that it somehow got reset to the factory default settings?

Answer (score 0):

Make the IP of you computer on the same vlan on the Wired side in this same subnet, try and connect with the IP address shown. You should be able to change it to DHCP or enter a valid static

[image]

Comment: I will give that a try plugged into the same VLAN. The AP is plugged into an interface configured on VLAN 3, which also has an interface configured as default gateway for the DHCP pool of the WLAN. There is already a VLAN 2 set up for 10.0.0.1/24 which some of our servers are on so I doubt that the AP would have an IP address in that range. Is it even possible for the AP to be on a different VLAN or network when the port it's plugged into is configured for VLAN 3?

Comment: if you mean the port is configured as "untagged vlan 3" then the WAP has no concept of vlans, it is vlan 1 or untagged vlan, put your laptop on vlan 3 and manually configure the IP address as 10.90.90.92, mask 255.255.255.0, gateway irrelevant, try and ping 10.90.90.91.